# SFDX: Cannot assign B2B Permission Set due to missing License

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze, b2b

I have created scratch org and installed B2B package into it. I`m trying to assign **Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings** PM but there is an error:

> Can't assign permission set Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings to user User User. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Custom Permission B2BCommerceAdmin is not valid for this Permission Set.

In Sandbox it`s fine, there is **B2B Commerce** license for Permission Set, as described here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=b2b_commerce_admin_perm.htm&type=5

But in scratch org, this license is missing.
[image]
I thought, that Scratch Orgs are like Sandboxes...

Is there any feature for B2B like CPQ that I can enable in *project-scratch-def.json*?
I did not find any here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

My json file:

```
{
  "orgName": "B2B Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities","StateAndCountryPicklist"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
        "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
        "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  } 
}
```

Has anyone tried that yet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use scratch orgs with B2B CloudCraze because, as you noticed, the license is -unfortunately- not available in scratch orgs.

So, you should use developer orgs or sandboxes for your development needs.

Comment: thanks, I`ve just realized that.

Comment: I've just asked it on the Trailblazer Community to see if there's an ETA or similar for this
https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00004t1vrx

Answer (score 1):

The license is now available, as outlined here: https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_scratch_org_b2b_commerce.htm&type=5&release=230